# Determine function of button on website in Firefox

Tags: firefox

Is there a way to figure out what a button on a website does (e.g., what JavaScript functions it kicks off or things like that) without clicking it in Firefox? For example, assume I don't know what the "ask question" button on the top right of this site does; can i figure that out without clicking it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several methods:

- right click the website background and select "View Source", find the button and/or link in question and see what it references
- right click the button and/or link in question and select "Inspect Element". This will take you to Firefox developer tools (which can also be accessed with <kbd>F12</kbd>), and you can see details of the element

In the case of form buttons, HTML links and JavaScript, it should be rather easy to see what a button does if you're familiar with those languages.

In the case of ASP/PHP driven websites, you might have a tough job figuring what a button does, as the ASP/PHP source code is run on the server, and as such, is not viewable by you.